# Azure Application Gateways - VMs from other Virtual Networks

Tags: azure, load-balancing, web-application-firewall

Can I use VMs (backend pools) on different virtual networks to the application gateway?

When I try, the VM list is empty.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can, but the virtual networks must be connected.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-components#backend-pools

> An application gateway can communicate with instances outside of the
> virtual network that it's in. As a result, the members of the backend
> pools can be across clusters, across datacenters, or outside Azure, as
> long as there's IP connectivity.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have peerings configured both ways... But nothing in vm list. Will it take private IPs?

Comment: Yes, it will not let you directly select VMs if they are not connected to the same VNet, but you can just type in their IP addresses.